# How Singleton affects unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

```
package singleton;

public class SingltonCls {
    private SingltonCls() {

    }
    private static class innerCls {
        private static SingltonCls INSTANCE = new SingltonCls();
    }
    public static SingltonCls getInstance() {
        return innerCls.INSTANCE;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

testing class is

```
package singleton;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class UnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        assertEquals(SingltonCls.getInstance().getValue(),12);
    }
}
```

Here I can test my Singleton class without any problem. Any body have any real time scenario where Singleton affects unit testing?

Comment: What do you mean by "Singleton affects unit testing"? What is the problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the Singleton itself, but in the way Singleton is often accessed - using static call to `MySingleton.getInstance()`. Such call cannot be easily replaced with a mock instance.

There is no problem with testing a Singleton that:

- implements a well defined interface,
- is only used through that interface, and
- is obtained in a way that allows for injecting a different implementation of the said interface.

---

Being able to swap a production implementation for a mock during testing is important because it enables you to really perform *unit* testing (i.e. testing of your component independent on other components), and allow you to test your component even if all dependencies cannot be fully replicated in a test environment (think a Singleton that sends e-mails while you don't want the test to send e-mails to your customers; or a singleton that accesses a database that you cannot install on test environment).

Answer (score 0):

If your singleton contains mutable state that cannot be reset between tests, then it will affect unit testing as the tests will need to be run in a specific order and the state accounted for.

If your singleton contains state that changes of time, it will prevent you reliably running tests in parallel.

You have two choices to running tests against a singleton without it making life hard for you:

1. Don't allow it to have any mutable state.
2. Don't use a singleton.